# Flexslider start button on first slide

Tags: flexslider

I was wondering if anyone has information on binding the play function to a button. I have been reading through the flexslider documentation and I can see there is the functionality available, but not how to fire it off. I am wanting to add a start button to the first slide of my slideshow and have that initiate the slideshow.  My js skills are at newbie level. Any information is greatly appreciated.

My basic slider code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.flexslider').flexslider({
   slideshow: false,
   useCSS: false,
   controlNav: false,
   directionNav: false,
   animationLoop: false

 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  slideshowSpeed: 3000,
  slideshow: false,
  useCSS: false,
  controlNav: false,
  directionNav: false,
  animationLoop: false
});
$('.start').click(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider("play")
 });
})
```